# How to change where Bacula stores backup volumes?

Tags: backup, bacula

The easiest way is to give an idea of desired file structure:

each backed up client is a subdirectory of /bak
e.g.
/bak/client1/
/bak/client2/

then within each client subdirectory Bacula Storage server should automatically create Volumes with format: $date_$time_$backup_type (one volume per backup run).
e.g.
/bak/client1/20120104_1654_full

what configuration could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could put together a python script, that dynamically generates volume name and directory, as shown here http://www.bacula.org/5.0.x-manuals/en/misc/misc/Python_Scripting.html